# In Node JS how to pass a variable to http.request callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest

I call http.request().end() and I need to pass a variable to the callback function.

How do I do this?

For my situation, a user accesses the server, the server sends an HTTP request to our API, and then the server needs to respond to that user with information returned from the HTTP request. I can't figure out a way to do that without using a global variable, which would be an issue, since if 2 people were to do this at once, both messages would be sent to the same user

Not sure how it would help but here's kind what I'm trying to do..

```
callback = function(response){
    //...
    respondToUser(userId);
}

function doStuff(userId){
    http.request({host:'www.google.com'}, callback).end();
}
```

Comment: *"I can't figure out a way to do that without using a global variable..."* No need for a global variable, just something your `request` callback closes over. If you show your code, we can help you with that.

Comment: If you don't use an anonymous function as the callback, you should just be able to pass in what you want easily.

Comment: I added a rough example of how I'm trying to use this. Maybe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something, and if I am, I apologize, I'm new to node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a "closure" where you are keeping the context with the function you are writing, like this

```
function doStuff(userId){
    var callback = function(response){
        //...
        respondToUser(userId);
    }

    http.request({host:'www.google.com'}, callback).end();
}
```

Comment: I considered this but I have several different functions that will need to do this sort of behavior, and copy pasting a hundred lines of parsing code several times is probably not a great solution. If this is the only solution, I guess I could probably combine all those functions.

Comment: You have probably organized your code in a way that would make it work in a procedural programming language (like Java or C++) -- the way you structure your code in a functional language like JavaScript is quite different

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I rewrote all the functions to be a single more complex function with the callback within, so thanks for the answer